# Ignoring specific line(s) from merge conflict evaluation?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

In my project there's `someFile`, whose the very first two lines look like this:

```
// This file is automatically generated
// Generated on 25.08.2020 15:01:00
```

The time in the second line varies.

This second line is therefore an unnecessary source of **merge conflicts** for my team.

Is there a way to somehow make git ignore that second line when evaluating git merge conflicts?

Comment: The short answer is no. There are some tricks that can help, but the "right answer" is usually *don't do that*. That is, don't commit *generated* files, just *generate* them from the actual source. Sometimes that's impractical, and then you have this sort of problem. You can write a merge driver to help out, but they're kind of cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no, there is not.  You should in general not check autogenerated files or other build products into the repository; this is one of many reasons why.

If you really want to do this, there are some approaches you can take:

- Use a smudge and clean filter to remove the date on check in and add it on checkout.
- Use a custom merge driver in `.gitattributes` to merge the file specially.  Every user performing a merge will be required to have that merge driver, and it will almost certainly not work for merges done by your hosting platform (because they won't have your merge driver).